# Raster appears like polygon in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, spatial-database

I copied rasters across into my geodatabase for a client but when they open the raster dataset in ArcMap they appear in tiles as shown in the image below. 
When I drag and drop individual rasters over they appear as they should but when adding the dataset I had a projection error message. So I added the correct projection to the dataset but I still have the same problem when adding the dataset as a whole to ArcMap.

What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by raster dataset? A raster catalog, a mosaic dataset? A single raster is a (raster) dataset.

Comment: Sorry. I mean a raster catalog. This is a collection of maybe over 100 lines of raster. I believe it might have something to do with some of them having different pixel depths to others?

Comment: What is the coordinate system of the raster catalog and of its individual rasters? How did you load these rasters into the raster catalog?

Comment: Coordinate system is WGS 1984 UTM Zone 30N. I loaded the rasters by right clicking and selecting "Load raster datasets" so I could copy over a few at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Open the properties of your raster catalog in the TOC of ArcMap and check the following option in the Display tab:

[image]

Also, there seems to be a coordinate system issue in your mxd since the scale is not visible:

[image]

But we can't say whether it's due to the coordinate system of your raster catalog vs the CS of the raster datasets it contains, or to the CS of (one of) the other layers in the TOC.

Comment: You are a lifesaver thankyou so much. It's always the little things! Scale is fine now that I have selected my coordinate system for the raster catalog.

Comment: Great, if the answer solved your question, market it as accepted then. Thanks!